# Why is my acceleration sensor still working after closing the activity?

Tags: java, android, sensors

I am developing an application that makes use of the **acceleration sensor** to move a ball across the screen. I have drawn the ball using **Canvas** and every time the drawing comes to "touch" the end of the screen a message is shown telling the user the corresponding side.

As shown in the following image:

[image]

The **Toast** shows a message: "movement to the left", translated from Spanish to English.

You see that the message is displayed correctly.

The problem arises when I click on the return button of the phone:

Your symptoms:

- The message of the image is displayed again depending on the orientation of the phone.
- The messages are apparently cycled, that is, even if you are not moving the messages are random.

[image]
[image]

The **Toast** messages behave as if they were still in the previous activity, that is, from which I have left. Sometimes it only shows the warning when I move the phone and other times without moving it several times and randomly.

The manual button of the main screen is the one that directs the view to the Activity of the first photograph with the ball.

Although in this view press the return button, the message keeps showing even when I returned to my applications screen.

The only way to eliminate this problem is by removing the application from the application bank and the process is the same again.

I emphasize that the problem only arises when I enter that view and return, before that does not happen.

I attach the main code:

```
btnManual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MovimientoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);                       
            }
```

Once in the MovimientoActivity.class

```
   public class MovimientoActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

        private DrawView view;  //Class where the ball is created with the accelerometer

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Cliclo-onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

            view = new DrawView(this, displaymetrics); //Se llama a esa vista
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F5B041"));
            setContentView(view);

            //Definimos usar toda la pantalla
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        }
    }
                });

Class DrawView.java

public class DrawView extends View implements SensorEventListener {

    Cliente cliente = null;

    Sensor accelerometer = null;
    SensorManager manager;

    static String TAG = "DrawView";

    int BLOQUEO_ARRIBA = 0;
    int BLOQUEO_ABAJO = 0;
    int BLOQUEO_DERECHO = 0;
    int BLOQUEO_IZQUIERDO = 0;

    private Bitmap pelota;

    public int ALTURA;

    public int ANCHO;
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics;

    Punto posicion = new Punto();

    final int X = 0;
    final int Y = 1;
    final int Z = 2;

    public DrawView(Context context, DisplayMetrics displaymetrics) {
        super(context);

        this.displaymetrics = displaymetrics;
        manager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        if (manager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).size() != 0) {

            accelerometer = manager.getSensorList(
                    Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
                    if (!manager.registerListener(this, accelerometer,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)) {
            }
        }

        try {
            AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
            InputStream inputStream;
            inputStream = assetManager.open("bola_2.png");
            pelota = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Obtenemos las medidas de la pantalla
        ALTURA = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        ANCHO = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // Modificamos la posicion de la bola en el eje X

        posicion.x -= event.values[X];
        //Comprobamos si se sale de la pantalla, y en ese caso, modificamos su valor
        if (posicion.x < 0) {

            if(BLOQUEO_IZQUIERDO == 0){
                Log.i(TAG, "onSensorChanged: izquierdo");
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Movimiento a la izquierda", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                BLOQUEO_DERECHO = 0;
                BLOQUEO_ARRIBA = 0;
                BLOQUEO_ABAJO = 0;

                BLOQUEO_IZQUIERDO++;
            }

            posicion.x = 0;
        }else if (posicion.x > this.ANCHO -pelota.getWidth()) {

            if(BLOQUEO_DERECHO == 0){
                Log.i(TAG, "onSensorChanged: derecho");
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Movimiento a la derecha", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                        
                BLOQUEO_IZQUIERDO = 0;
                BLOQUEO_ARRIBA = 0;
                BLOQUEO_ABAJO = 0;

                BLOQUEO_DERECHO++;
            }

            posicion.x = this.ANCHO - pelota.getWidth();
        }
        //Modificamos la posicion de la bola en el eje Y
        posicion.y += event.values[Y];
        //Comprobamos si se sale de la pantalla, y en ese caso, modificamos su valor
        if (posicion.y < 0) {

            if(BLOQUEO_ARRIBA == 0){
                Log.i(TAG, "onSensorChanged: arriba");
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Movimiento hacia arriba", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                BLOQUEO_DERECHO = 0;
                BLOQUEO_IZQUIERDO = 0;
                BLOQUEO_ABAJO = 0;

                BLOQUEO_ARRIBA++;
            }
            posicion.y = 0;

        }else if (posicion.y > this.ALTURA - pelota.getHeight()) {

            if(BLOQUEO_ABAJO == 0){
                Log.i(TAG, "onSensorChanged: abajo");
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Movimiento hacia abajo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                        
                BLOQUEO_DERECHO = 0;
                BLOQUEO_ARRIBA = 0;
                BLOQUEO_IZQUIERDO = 0;

                BLOQUEO_ABAJO++;
            }

            posicion.y = this.ALTURA - pelota.getHeight();
        }
        //Método invalidate para llamar onDraw
        invalidate();


    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(pelota, posicion.x, posicion.y, null);
    }    
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {    
    }        
}
```

The variables that I have declared as BLOQUEO are because I only need the sensor to inform me of the event once, so if it is fulfilled I will do another action until another end is "touched".

Well so far this is the problem. In the end my goal is to prevent the sensor from continuing to work once the screen of the ball is removed or in case it stops working in the background if that is the problem.

I appreciate the help you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make manager a public property so you can access it from your activity.

```
public class DrawView extends View implements SensorEventListener {

Cliente cliente = null;

Sensor accelerometer = null;
public SensorManager manager;
...
}
```

now unregister listeners in MovimientoActivity onPause():

```
protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     if(view!=null)if(view.manager!=null)view.manager.unregisterListener(view);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to unregister your listener from SensorManager while exiting application/Activity.
For that you have to override onDestroy method within your activity.
refer this page for all methods
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager

Comment: How would I apply it if my SensorManager and SensorManager have it in the DrawView class and not in the Activity itself where I can put the methods of onDestroy or onResume?